# Comparison between Bootstrap-Vue and Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have used Vuejs for developing my frontend and now I have to style it.
I came across  [Bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/) . Which will be better to use Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap-vue. Are they same or is there is an advantage to use Bootstap-vue.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Some Bootstrap 4 functions require **jQuery**, **Popper.js**, and these functions will conflict with Vue. *(These functions modify the DOM directly. Vue won't keep track of these modifications. Any changes made using jQuery could be overwritten by Vue.)*

These functions include:

- Affix
- Alert
- Button
- Carousel
- Collapse
- Dropdown
- Modal
- Popover
- Scrollspy
- Tab
- Tooltip

`Bootstrap-vue` converted most of these functions into Vue, so that it works as expected.

**If you only want to use Bootstrap CSS and not its JS related functions**, using `Bootstrap 4` directly will be more straight forward and requires less time spent learning how `Bootstrap-vue` works.

**Else**, use `Bootstrap-vue`.

If you are not sure, `Bootstrap-vue` seems like a less risky choice.

Comment: The `Bootstrap-vue` plugin has not been released for the best part of a year even though the github code base is getting daily commits.

Comment: As an update, BootstrapVue has been actively updated for the most part of 2019, and is at release 2.0.0-rc.25 as of the time of writing this comment.

Comment: See details right near the top of the "Getting Started" docs at https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Comment: They don't really conflict. They just work independently, Attaching vuejs is still possible