# Want to integrate Asp.net core and Vue JS using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have just started creating POC for a project. I am using 
ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Vue JS ( to create view only).

I have gone through the following link about difference between bootstrap vs bootstrap vue
[Comparison between Bootstrap-Vue and Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127800/comparison-between-bootstrap-vue-and-bootstrap-4)

But I am using both Bootstrap and Bootstrap-vue(Because it gives table plugin and other feature). The reason is that few pages of report will be developed in asp.net core.

Is this correct approach?

Comment: What do you mean with `i use both Bootstrap AND bootstrap-vue`?

Comment: This is a multi page application. There will be a few pages(login page,report related pages) that will use Bootstrap 4 and there view will be created without using vue js.

Comment: This is very strange that I forgot that Bootstrap 4 is required to work with Bootstrap vue. Therefore, I think my question does not make any sense. I am ok with the way I am implementing asp.net core with vue js.